# Is there a term for saying something like: "thank you for remaining professional and not taking your frustrations out on staff"

Tags: psychology, psycholinguistics

I saw this verbiage on a sign, and I just thought there has to be a term for this way of speaking.  It seems like the assumption is that I will be "UN" professional and they are trying to preempt a situation from happening, and as such, it seems condescending.  I am wondering if there is a psychological term for this way of speaking down to people.

Comment: Something more specific than *condescending* or *patronising*? What terms have you considered and rejected? (And by the way, lots of people do take their fustrations out on staff, so it's hardly as if they're reacting to a problem that doesn't exist, even if you can debate whether the sign is the best way to address it.)

Comment: Presumptuous? Jumping the gun? Assuming the worst? Not giving the benefit of the doubt? Lecturing us? Berating us before we even did sh!t?

Comment: Sign probably put up by staff.

Comment: It seems more sarcastic than condescending to me. It would be like a store having a sign "Please don't shoplift".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The comment needn't be necessarily condescending in tone.

If, for example, a boss is speaking to an employee whom he or she knows is experiencing some frustration on the job, the comment can be quite complimentary, particularly if the employee is expressing their frustration one-on-one with the boss and not in front of fellow employees.

The particulars of the scenario determine if the comment is or isn't condescending.

I like your use of the word ***preempt***, since bosses sometimes try to "head someone off at the pass."

> To head someone off at the pass or to cut someone off at the pass
> means to prevent someone from accomplishing something, to forestall an
> event, to intercept and redirect someone. Synonyms for these idioms
> that may be found in a thesaurus are ambush, block, thwart[1](https://search.yahoo.com/yhs/search?hspart=trp&hsimp=yhs-001&grd=1&type=Y167_F163_202037_051923&p=the%20meaning%20of%20to%20%22head%20things%20off%20at%20the%20pass%22).

In that way, an intelligent boss both compliments the employee and at the same time reinforces an important workplace value.

What do we call the comment? How about "a preemptive yet complimentary locution"? Just an idea.